# How to access closed-over local variable in MemberExpression?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reflection

I am writing some expression analyzing code that needs to access the value of parameters in an `Expression<Action>`.

The below code works whenever the parameter is a member or property on the source object, but fails when the member is a close-over local variable. How can I get access to the anonymous type that is closing over the local variable so that I can access the local variable?

Here's the error message:

```
Test method FluentCache.Test.ClosureTest.Test threw exception: 
System.ArgumentException: Field 'localVariable' defined on type 'Test.ClosureTest+<>c__DisplayClass2' is not a field on the target object which is of type 'Test.ClosureTest'
```

Here's the simplified code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    Func<int, int> myAction = i => i + 1;
    int localVariable = 10;

    int analyzed = (int)GetFirstParameterValue(this, () => myAction(localVariable));

    Assert.AreEqual(localVariable, analyzed);
}

public object GetFirstParameterValue(object source, Expression<Action> expression)
{
    var invocationExpression = expression.Body as InvocationExpression;
    var parameterExpression = invocationExpression.Arguments[0] as MemberExpression;
    var parameterFieldInfo = parameterExpression.Member as FieldInfo;

    //ERROR: This code will fail because the local variable is "wrapped" in a closure anonymous type
    //How do I get access to the anonymous type in order to retrieve the value?
    object fieldValue = parameterFieldInfo.GetValue(source);
    return fieldValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object containing the value of your field is contained in the `Expression` property of `parameterExpression`.  Thus change the second to last line of your code to:

```
object fieldValue = parameterFieldInfo.GetValue(
    ((ConstantExpression)parameterExpression.Expression).Value);
```

The instance we're passing in is the constant closure type available via `parameterExpression`.

[Here's a .Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EuzxVj) demonstrating the solution.